# How to link .cpp and .lib files to create a .so file?

Tags: c++, gcc, g++, .so, .lib

I have four files which are developed for the user code of Star-ccm+:
main.cpp, uclib.cpp, uclib.h, UserFunctions.lib
The header file is included in the .cpp files.
Now, I must link these files together to create a .so file. I tried the following code but it's useful just for the creation of a .so file out of a .cpp file, not linking different files together:
g++ -fPIC -shared *.cpp -o libuser.so
Please let me know how can I do that?

Comment: `.lib` files are typically used by vc++ toolchain and can only be used on Windows.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. So, you mean I have to change it to .a? Do you have any idea how?

Comment: You need to obtain source code for that library and build a static library using gcc toolchain